# Remove Wordpress Cache Definitely

Tags: wordpress, caching

I have a WordPress install without any cache plugin (I had W3 Cache and Wp Super Cache installed but now they were removed) and the site still be caching. When I enter I see old news and when I manually refresh the browser it updates.

Any idea? What is happening?

Comment: Are you seeing the old posts when when you are logged in?

Comment: When I am logged it works good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by APC Cache. http://php.net/manual/es/book.apc.php

I disable it and now everything it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the cache folder in `wp-content/cache/` and also the W3TC configuration files and folders in wp-content, such as `w3-total-cache-config.php`, `db.php`, `advanced-cache.php` and the `w3tc` folder.

Delete any cache directives in wp-config.php, such as

```
define('WP_CACHE', true); //Added by WP-Cache Manager

define( 'WPCACHEHOME', '/home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/' ); //Added by WP-Cache Manager
```

Delete any caching and expires headers directives in the root .htaccess file, too, such as bracketed by `## START W3TC ##`, etc.

And be sure you have cleared your own browser cache.

Comment: I have done that and the site still be caching. Could be something with APC?